# Shell command to fetch only the filename

Tags: shell, file

I have a bunch of files in a directory. I want to copy the same files to a different directory with a different extension.

```
$ pwd
source_path
$ ls
Test File 1.xyz
test File 2.xyz
Blah Blah.xyz
```

I want to copy them to a different directory.

```
$ pwd
dest_path
$ ls
Test File 1.abc
test File 2.abc
Blah Blah.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Innumerable ways to accomplish this, but perhaps the most straight-forward and readable would be to use a substring replacement:

```
cd source_path

for file in *.xyz; do
    cp -av "$file" "dest_path/${file/xyz/abc}"
done
```

Comment: `${file/.xyz/.abc}` may be safer as real extension strings (eg. `c`) could be easily found and replaced in the file name too.

Comment: @Kenavoz agreed. There is also the lesser used ${variable/%foo/bar} substitution which looks at the end of the string. Both coupled together should be pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 steps

```
cp "source_path/*.xyz" dest_path
rename 's/\.xyz$/\.abc/' "dest_path/*.xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

With this longer method, you source_path files can have file extenssion, if that's what you need

```
cd $source_path

new_file_ext=".abc"
ls > files.tmp # Put ls output to a temporary file
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do # read the temporary file line by line
  file_name=$(echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1) # split the name at the '.' and keep part one
  cp $line "$dest_path"/"$file_name""$new_file_ext" # copy file at dest and add new extenssion 
done < "files.tmp"
```